# Bootstrap Carousel Issues on Windows 8

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've implemented the Bootstrap Carousel within my website. Whilst is works perfectly on Firefox, Chrome and Safari there is of course an issue with Internet Explorer (Windows 8 Versions).

Whilst the NavBar is the correct size for the window, the actual carousel image appears narrowed as if it was being viewed on a mobile screen.

To enable responsiveness I've added this line of code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Have you tried http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie10-width ? Add `@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }` and the extra JS.

Comment: Yes - it's strange, it's just the 'carousel' component that's affected, everything else seems fine.